Edit Active X Spin button via VBA?
I am trying to use a macro to change the properties of a Active X spin Button.  Can this be done?
I know it can be done with a Forms Control spin button, but i am specifically looking to use it to change a active x spin button.
More specifically, i am trying to write a macro for the linking of the cell for the 120 different spin buttons.

What have you tried so far?  What's the specific problem you're having while trying to get this working?

The short answer is, "Yes," you can affect the properties with VBA.  You just need to be able to interact with the correct shape.  As you have tagged vba, please put in the code you have tried thusfar, noting that SO is not a code-for-you service, but does specialize in resolving specific issues.

Try either ActiveSheet.OleObjects or ActiveSheet.ScrollBars objects.

Black Cat, are you suggesting something like Activesheet.OleObjeccts.LinkedCell = ..... would work?

For the sake of a quick check if something is a spin button:
Sub test()
    With Sheets(1)
        Dim sh As Object:  For Each sh In .Shapes
            If sh.Type = 12 And TypeName(sh.OLEFormat.Object.Object) = "SpinButton" Then
                Debug.Print sh.Name
            End If
        Next sh
    End With
End Sub

Once you determine if you have the right shape, you can check its parameters with VBA and modify them.

What outcome tells me if i have the right shape or not.   Before the macro runs.  there is only one spinbutton on the doc.

@hamfam edited to make it more direct; the TypeName and the .Type give different parameters to help identify if you have the correct shape/control, and if those criterion are met, then you can perform an action using that shape, e.g., debug.print sh.name in the above script.

All ActiveX objects on a sheet can be accessed using the OLEObjects-collection of the sheet. But be carefull, OLEObjects are not only ActiveX controls. An OLEObject is a container for different kind of "things".
So the first thing is to check the OLEType of the OLEObject - it must have the value xlOLEControl (= 2) to identify ActiveX controls. The control itself is stored (or, to be more precise, referenced) in the property Object of the OLEObject. To figure out what kind of ActiveX object we have, just check the type (using the function TypeName). Type name for SpinButtons is "SpinButton".
Equipped with that, we can access and modify various properties. Some properties, eg the position and size, are stored on OLEObject level. Also the linked cell is stored on this level. The ActiveX control holds the control-specific values, eg Min and Max value, the current value or the color.
The following code gives you an idea - if you have more than one SpinButton, you need of course an idea how to distinguish the single controls - for example by name or by it's position.
Sub test()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Dim oleObj As OLEObject
        For Each oleObj In .OLEObjects
            If oleObj.OLEType = xlOLEControl Then  ' ActiveX Control
                Dim ctrl
                Set ctrl = oleObj.Object
                If TypeName(ctrl) = "SpinButton" Then
                    Debug.Print oleObj.Name & " at " & oleObj.Left & "/" & oleObj.Top & " is linked to " & oleObj.LinkedCell
                    
                    oleObj.Width = 100
                    oleObj.Height = 24
                    
                    ctrl.Min = 10
                    ctrl.Max = 123
                    ctrl.Value = 50
                    ctrl.BackColor = vbBlue
                End If
            End If
        Next oleObj
    End With
End Sub


I ran your code above, the immediate box states "SpinButton1 at 400.5/73.5 is linked to D4".  I believe this proves that i have an OLEObject?  After going back to the document, i see that it changed the value and color.  Thanks.  I'll see what i can do with this.

ActiveX controls on a worksheet are wrapped in OLEObjects.  This should demystify it somewhat.
Sub Demo()
    Dim Map As New Collection
    Set Map = GetOLEObjectsByType(Sheet1, "SpinButton")
    Dim Spinner As MSForms.SpinButton
    Dim Item As Excel.OLEObject
    For Each Item In Map
        Set Spinner = Item.Object
        Application.Goto Item.TopLeftCell
        Debug.Print Item.TopLeftCell.Address(0, 0)
        Stop
    Next
End Sub

Function GetOLEObjectsByType(ws As Worksheet, ControlType As String) As Collection
    Dim Map As New Collection
    Dim Item As Excel.OLEObject
    For Each Item In Sheet1.OLEObjects
        If TypeName(Item.Object) = ControlType Then Map.Add Item
    Next
    
    Set GetOLEObjectsByType = Map
End Function

